# sqlite3.operationalError: no such column: sales_id

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

so I have defined all the columns in the table named (Sales) and I created this delete record and update record function and both don't seem to work and it throws the same error in the case of both the functions, even after clearly defining the column sales_id

The error: sqlite3.operationalError: no such column: sales_id

query database is simply a function to insert all the records from the database and insert into the treeview

below is my code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Bizzapp.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute(""" CREATE TABLE if not exists Sales(
                 sales_id VarChar,
                 product_id VarChar,
                 customer_id VarChar,
                 quantity int,
                 price int,
                 order_date date,
                 UOM unit
          )""")

conn.commit()
conn.close()



def update_record():

    conn = sqlite3.connect('Bizzapp.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    for s in my_tree_sales.get_children():

          my_tree_sales.delete(s)

    c.execute(""" UPDATE Sales SET
                       sales_id = :sales,
                       product_id = :product,
                       customer_id = :customer,
                       quantity = :quantity,
                       price = :price,
                       order_date = :date,
                       UOM = :uom
                       
                       WHERE sales_id = :sales""",
                {
                    'sales': entry1.get(),
                    'product': entry2.get(),
                    'customer': entry3.get(),
                    'quantity': entry4.get(),
                    'price': entry5.get(),
                    'date': entry6.get(),
                    'uom': entry7.get()
                })

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    query_database()



def delete_record():

        conn = sqlite3.connect('Bizzapp.db')
        c = conn.cursor()

        recs = my_tree_sales.get_children()

        for r in recs:
            my_tree_sales.delete(r)

        lookup_record = entry1.get()

        c.execute("DELETE from Sales WHERE sales_id = ?", (lookup_record,))

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

        query_database()
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. You don't have a `sales_id` column in the `Sales` table. Show the table definition.

Comment: ok, let me add the table defination

Comment: i've added it, hope you can see..

Comment: Maybe the table already exists and it doesn't have that column. `if not exists` skips the query if the table already exists.

Comment: actually i changed the spelling of the table cause I was facing a similar problem in the table with a different name.. so this seems to be a new table and yet the problem doesn't seem to go.. i can try creating a table again.. cause I think if I don't include the "if not exists" statement then it will create a table every time the program is executed..

Comment: No, it will get an error because the table already exists. You would have to `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Sales` first to create the table all the time.

Comment: BTW, why do you need `SET sales_id = :sales` -- you're just setting it to the value it already has.